# SSL Handshake random number?

Tags: tls, authentication, random

I realized all of the phase of the handshake but I do not understand how it does that from the two randomly generated numbers are unable to generate a session key that the client and the server uses for symmetric encryption .
if someone explain to me how it works I would be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being done by using the

- [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange protocol when you aim for Forward Secrecy (Authentication-Key = RSA, Encrpytion-Key = DH-negotiated)
- RSA in non Forward Secrecy scenarios (Authentication/Encryption-Key = RSA).

The latter has the disadvantage that an attacker that can get hold of your private key can also decrypt all past communication - whereas this is not possible by using DH and therefore a different key for encryption.

Comment: The RSA handshake is pretty common as well.

Comment: True - unfortunately. I was a bit too Forward Secrecy focussed. Good remark.